# Not allowing Whitespace(_) at start or more than two between words

Tags: php, regex

i have this regex `the _ is the whitespace`

```
^([a-z]{4}+)?_([A-Z]{4}+)?_(\d{4}+)?$
```

which allows `alpha_BETA_1920`, I expect it to allow the following values too

`alpha`

`BETA`

`1920`

`alpha_BETA`

`alpha_1920`

`BETA_1920`

The problem is that the `_` is static, So all the values above are `false`, And my RegEx treats the next `false` values as `true`

`alpha__`

`_BETA_`

`__1920`

`alpha_BETA_`

`alpha__1920`

`_BETA_1920`

---

P.S. My actual `RegEx` contains more than `6 words` instead of the `3 words` as here.

The `_` isn't an actualy underscore, Replace it with , I used it because the `` didn't allow me to use it at the beginning or the end of the text.

Comment: Please edit your question and clearly show us positive and negative matches.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen better now?

Comment: Are the string on a per line basis or as words?

Comment: @Jan as a full word consisted of words..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `a_A_` is valid in it.

Comment: And which programming language do you use?

Comment: @Jan i use pcre(php)

Comment: Something like this: https://regex101.com/r/gu6LhR/1 ?

Comment: @Jan Somehow, But after replacing the `_` with `whitespace` it doesn't catch it properly, Also it doesn't accept numbers at the end, If possible i want to understand how to prevent starting or finishing `_` or double `__` in between.

Comment: You are only adding more confusion to your question by using `_` to represent whitespace characters.  Be very literal/exact in your question details and output requirements.  Those of us that are here to help have a firm handle on regex.  Tell us the whole truth and nothing but the truth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try enclosing the whole "letter plus underscore" sub pattern into a group and apply the `?` quantifier. Also, the number shouldn't be optional, should it?

```
^([a-z]+_)?([A-Z]+_)?(\d+)$
```

Comment: by doing this i get valid false values from `az_` and `az_AZ_` but not from `az` or `AZ`, Since it requires `_` at their end by adding `?` to `(\d+)`, `(\d+)` is missing the `?`, Your code works perfectly if i removed the `?` from it.

Comment: Sadly, No, It serves my RegEx only if it is `(\d+)` but mine is `(\d+)?`

Comment: @Toleo Okay, it seems like I still do not understand your requirements. Do you want all 3 things (small letter, capital letter, number) to be optional but at least one of them must be present?

Comment: All of them are `optional`, But in my original RegEx, If i just wrote `___` it would be valid, But this is false, I expect 1 `word` with 0 `_` OR 2 words with 1 `_` between them OR 3 words with 1 `_` between each one of them.,  I'l try updating the question to clarify it more.

Comment: @Toleo Now you are saying "words". Do you want to match all word characters (`\w`)? Or just small letters for the first one, capital letters for the second one and digits for the third one?

Comment: I'm planning to `limit` the words lenght doing `[a-z]}{12}` later, That why i use `a-z` instead of `\w`

Comment: @mickmackusa i'm really trying to clearify it, But all i'm trying to say is, prevent `start or end (_)`  And allow only `one (_) between words If there is more than one word, like az_AZ or az_AZ_09`.

Comment: @Toleo and you want max 3 words?

Comment: It is actually hovers between 3 to 6 words, But i didn't think it would matter.

Answer (score 1):

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrLDkE/2)

Pattern: `/\b[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)?(?:_\d+)?\b|\b(?:[a-z]+_)?(?:[A-Z]+_)?\d+\b|\b[A-Z]+\b/`

It matches from the front, or matches from the back of the string, or it matches the middle.  See demo for visual.

---

Or instead of wordboundaries, you can use anchors for improved speed:

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrLDkE/3)

Pattern:

```
/^[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)?(?:_\d+)?$|^(?:[a-z]+_)?(?:[A-Z]+_)?\d+$|^[A-Z]+$/
```

Or just 2 anchors around a non-capturing group:

```
/^(?:[a-z]+(?:_[A-Z]+)?(?:_\d+)?|(?:[a-z]+_)?(?:[A-Z]+_)?\d+|[A-Z]+)$/
```

Comment: Last one solves it, But, Can't it be more dynamic? Since i use 6 words in my original code instead of 3 as i used here, To apply it, That would be a long expr imo, Or is this the actual way to do it?

Comment: @Toleo I can only solve the question as it is posted.  I can't see your data.  If you post better sample data, I may be able to improve my answer.  But who knows.  It is 1:30am for me, so if you are going to change your question, please do so before I go to bed.

Comment: Do you mean dynamic like this:  https://regex101.com/r/DrLDkE/4  This doesn't valid the non-whitespace characters (words) but it does check for valid white spaces and total word count.

Comment: @Toleo The problem with your new edit, is that you keep giving us strings with 3 non-whitespace substrings, and then telling us that your ACTUAL project has 6.  Why do you do this?  Why not give us more accurate data?

Comment: yes, something exactly like this, But i want to apply it on my `RegEx` to allow certain characters and special characters in some parts.

Comment: oh, that the problem, I used `_` as if it is a `whitespace` because the ```` doesn't allow a start whitespace or ending whitespace, So i had to use `_` as a defintion to a whitespace, I don't use `_` but ` ` instead of it.

Comment: If you need to validate each non-whitespace substring a specific way, then you will need a more verbose pattern -- similar to what I posted in my answer.

Comment: @Toleo My eyes are closing on me.  Are you going to clarify your question? or is my answer sufficient.  I can't provide anything more unless you improve your question clarity.

Comment: if i used the actual RegEx `^([a-z]{4}+)?_([A-Z]{4}+)?_(\d{4}+)?_(\d{4})?_{[a-z]{4}}?_([A-Z]{4})$` to apply your answer on it, Wouldn't it be a long RegEx?

Comment: and are all 6 components optional?

Comment: Oh,excuse me, last one wasn't optional, that all.

Comment: Do you mean that the all valid strings will contain and end with `[A-Z]{4}`?  Do you mean each "word" will have 4 characters? or at least 4 characters?

Comment: yes, If making it valid by making the first value is the strict value Would make it easier and fast i have no problem with that too.

Comment: How about this? https://regex101.com/r/DrLDkE/5  This requires the last component, and all others are optional.  If any optional components exist, they MUST be followed by a space.  This also stressed the required order of the components -- valid strings cannot be shuffled around.  Why is `4` the  magic number?  is that right? can it be less than 4? greater than 4?

Comment: The "back-to-back" digit components can be merged like this: `^([a-z]{4} )?([A-Z]{4} )?(\d{4} ){0,2}([a-z]{4} )?([A-Z]{4})$`

Comment: yes, that works as intended, That makes @Sweeper answer valid on the actual RegEx, Didn't notice his answer was on it.

Comment: This is what my answer does.  It has 3 "alternatives" to allow all components to be optional.  First it requires the first component and makes the other optional OR it requires the last and the others are optional OR it requires the lone middle component.  This covers all angles for your 3 component sample data.

Comment: i'm making a better question to clarify things about it now, I'll make it better than the question i made before, Because i got lost in it too.

Comment: i hope this is better https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465620/what-is-the-proper-way-for-a-table-like-stairs